# Magento Reviews Management - Edit Grid

Tags: magento

In magento admin I can only see up to 50 characters of review text. How can I edit template etc so I can view the whole review text?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to override the `_prepareColumns()` function under `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid`

there is below code section

```
    $this->addColumn('detail', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('review')->__('Review'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'index'         => 'detail',
        'filter_index'  => 'rdt.detail',
        'type'          => 'text',
        'truncate'      => 50,
        'nl2br'         => true,
        'escape'        => true,
    ));
```

in which truncate is used, you need to increase the limit.

Comment: I did increase to 500 and cleared cache etc but still truncated to 50 characters.

Comment: @James Sorry by mistake I have put the wrong column code, Please have a look on updated answer now.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I relised that and actually edited the correct column but it doesn't work. Very strange.

Comment: May be you have already override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid block in your local or community codePool

Comment: Now its time to debug yourself using breakpoint log etc in any PHP IDE like NetBeans.....